# Using column name as part of foreign key relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, drop-down-menu, foreign-keys

As part of the application I am building I want to store the values of all dropdowns in a single table, where all table/column combinations that represent a dropdown will be able to reference it.

Something like the below:

```
CREATE TABLE dropdown_def
(
    id int,
    table_id int,
    field_name TEXT,
    value TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (table_id, field_name, value)
);

INSERT INTO test1.dropdowns (id, table_id, field_name, value)
VALUES (1, 1, 'status', 'active');

CREATE TABLE clients 
(
    id int,
    table_id int,
    status TEXT,
   FOREIGN KEY (table_id, 'status', status) 
        REFERENCES dropdowns (table_id, field_name, value)
);
```

I tried the above but with no surprise it seems you cannot use the actual column name as part of the foreign key constraint.

Is there any other way of using the column identifier in a FK?

Comment: Not a good idea... There shouldn't be multiple entities in one table, each entity should have its own table. Do not think application, or even worse here, UI centric, think data centric. If your clients have statuses, create and reference a status table. If their addresses have a country, create and reference a country table, etc.

Comment: I would not consider a good idea to use CLOBs as part of a unique constraint. What's the need for it? It can have significant performance implications as well.

Comment: @sticky bit Absolutely agree with what you are saying and it applies to almost every case. But like everything, it depends. When you start building abstractions on top of the database then you begin bending the rules of the relational model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a constant stored computed column for the FK.

```
CREATE TABLE clients 
(
    id int,
    table_id int,
    status TEXT,
    refcolname text GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('status') STORED, 
    FOREIGN KEY (table_id, refcolname, status) 
        REFERENCES dropdowns (table_id, field_name, value)
);
```

Really I would advice against the design like that. Why to create a united table of lookups just to get troubles referencing its parts. Use the EAV pattern only if it is absolutely inevitable, for example a set of lookup tables is to be defined by a user at runtime.

Comment: thanks for the answer it is similar to what I had in mind as well. in general I agree EAV pattern has many drawbacks. In this case though each dropdown value is treated as string so no special conversions are required as stated in the Attribute part of the EAV.